Factor Analysis: high proportion of variance explained by a single variable
I am running an exploratory factor analysis in R (psych package).
I have 73 observations (~40 complete for all variables) and 10 variables. Parallel analysis suggested 2 underlying factors.
This is my code:
psych_fit2<- fa(FA.df, nfactors=2, rotate= 'oblimin',fm="ml")

psych_fit2<-kaiser(psych_fit2, rotate = "oblimin") #kaiser normalisation and rotation
print.psych(psych_fit2, sort=TRUE)
This is my output:

However, the loadings and proportion variance explained seem to suggest that the 2 factors just represent 1) Powers_25 variable and 2) Gabor_75 variable (each factor explains 99.5% of variance in each variable).
Does this therefore suggest 0 underlying factors? I had poor results for both Bartlett's and KMO test, which I realise indicate that factor analysis is not recommended. I also have relatively low correlations (see below).I just want to understand how the factor structure has come about.

ADDITIONAL REQUESTED INFO:
Varimax rotation results:

KMO results:
Overall MSA: 0.44
McGurk_Perceptual: 0.37
McGurk_Cognitive: 0.43
Powers_NoTone: 0.45
Powers_25: 0.44
Sentence_Pred: 0.41
Sentence_Unpred: 0.39
Gabor_25: 0.48
Gabor_75: 0.46
Memory: 0.47
Mooney: 0.35
Scree plot:


What is the overall KMO and individual variables KMOs? Also, show please the scree-plot ofvthe eigenvalues of the correlation matrix.

Also note that the "strange" loadings pattern you've faced is not atypical with oblique rotation. For display purposes here, do varimax rotation.

@ttnphns information now added thanks


KMO (MSA) for all the items are quite low which days that partial correlations prevail. You data are bad for factor analysis. (Maybe you are better off with just PCA.). 2) In any case, the scree plot votes for just one factor maximum, not two.


@ttnphns thanks yes I realise the factor analysis isn’t a great idea here but interested in whether the two ‘1’ loadings here are essentially just representing 2 of the task variables. In which case I don’t know why the algorithm has chosen these as factors and not loaded high on other variables - I guess I thought the loadings would be unstable

You've got two variables with high communalities. Then requested oblique rotation. No wonder the axes came almost right through these two points.
